# Create a List<T> with T being an anonymous type using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

Let's say we have the `List<Item> data`, and the `Item` class is defined as below:

```
public class Item
{
    public double Station { get; set; }
    public double Area { get; set; }

    ...
    // other properties present in the class

}
```

**Now how can we create a new `List<T>` out of `List<Item>`, so that `T` is anonymous type having only `double Station` and `double Area` as its properties.**

I know how to extract all of the station and area values into a `List<double> data2` but what I want above is different.

```
var data2 = data
    .SelectMany(x => new[] { x.Station, x.Area })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is really a bad idea. Better put those properties into an interface and then create a List of that interface.

Comment: @CSharpie Thanks CSharpie for the idea, but I actually need this one time in a specific algorithm, so using an interface seems like an overkill!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you need is...

```
var data2 = data
    .Select(x => new { x.Station, x.Area })
    .ToList();
```

You don't need `SelectMany` here, usually it is used to flatten the hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes you are so immersed in programming that you miss the obvious!

Comment: True, happens in busy schedule :-)